# Is it possible to use developer's local host name in shared launchSettings.json file?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, configuration

I have a pretty standard launchSettings.json file where we either launch with IIS Express or IIS.  When we launch to IIS, we need to use our local hostname due to the cert we use for HTTPS.  The problem is team members keep accidentally committing their local changes to the file so it becomes a pain point.  Is there a way to override per developer without completing ignoring the file?

Approach #1: As with web.config/app.settings, something like launchSettings.development.json (tried, didn't work, maybe I did it wrong?)

Approach #2: Exclude from source control completely and each person deals with it (not very nice)

Approach #3: Eliminate launch settings in favor of code-based configuration and command line parameters to select (would prefer to keep configuration separate)

Approach #4: Consume environment variables within launchSettings.  This seems ideal, but if it's possible, I'm not seeing it.

Approach #5: Something else entirely?  What's the best practice?

Current configuration:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://me.domain.local/MySiteDev",
      "sslPort": 443
    }
  }
```

Desired (approach #4):

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://{COMPUTERNAME}.{USERDNSDOMAIN}/MySiteDev",
      "sslPort": 443
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Arian Kulp, it seems to be impossible get host name in launchSettings.json.

Comment: That's what it looks like. Disappointing.  What's the best way to manage this situation?